# tailwind css flex-wrap evenly when overflowing / wrapping

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a list that is dynamically generated, this sits in a flex wrapper, it nicely wraps dependent on browser size, however, when it overflows and wraps, it only displays the overflow on the 2nd line. What I'd like to happen is that all the list elements are distributed evenly over both lines rather than just the overflow falling onto the next line. I don't know the number of entries required as this is data dependent.

This is the basics of what I've done, the real links are generated in a loop within a twig template

```
<ul class="flex-1 flex-wrap">
<li>link1 </li>
<li>link2 </li>
<li>link3 </li>
...
<li>last link </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you are generating the real links in a loop with a Twig template, then shouldn't you know the number of entries?

Comment: I don't know the screen resolution in the template, so I have no idea how many lines I will need. If the browser is re-sized this will change anyway, hence looking for a CSS solution as it will adjust to the user's demands.

Comment: Oh, OK, thank you for the clarification. Are you looking for a CSS-only solution? I don't think one exists.

Comment: Thanks, I was beginning to think I was out of luck with pure CSS.